# Why is $\mathbb{R}$ not quasi isometric to $[0,\infty)$

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory

So I'm reading Bowditch's lecture notes on geometric group theory and gave this as an example, but I didn't quite follow his reasoning. I was wondering if someone could explain why these two spaces are not quasi isometric. Thanks.

Excerpt from Bowditch:
[image]

EDIT: So I get everything up to the point where he derives a contradiction. I don't see why $|\phi(0)-\phi(p)|$ agrees with $a-\phi(0)$ up to a constant where the constant is independent of $a$. This is what is troubling me.

Comment: It might be helpful to include exactly what you don't follow.

Comment: That's simply because $a$ is larger than $\phi(0)$ so $|a-\phi(0)| = a -\phi(0)$ but also $|a-\phi(0)| \leq |a-\phi(p)| + |\phi(p) -\phi(0)|$, and $|a-\phi(p)|$ is bounded independantly of $a$

Comment: I still  don't get the contradiction. Sorry if I'm a bit slow.

Comment: Oh never mind I got it. The contradiction is that we have $p$ bounded, but were free to vary $a$.